# Hibernate.initialize fails with org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

A have two hibernate entities and a simple 1:N collection relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "root", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<Position> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }
}
```

and a Spring MVC web application loads the root entity and initializes the lazy collection:

```
@Transactional
public Root findFullById(Long id) {
    Root root = (Root) getSession().get(Root.class, id);
    Hibernate.initialize(root.getPositions()); // this line fails
    return root;
}
```

There are **NO** database operations before this method.

This works fine with almost all enities in my Oracle 11 DB but some (seems random) are failing with "org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session". As I understand this happens because the session in the PersistentSet is closed but why it is closed in the first place?

The most strange thing is that if I put a breakpoint on this line and invoke Hibernate.initialize() within the debugger (i.e. in eclipse Inspect window), it loads the collection successfully.

**What could close the session? Is there any good staring place to debug this (i.e. breakpoint somewhere in the Hibernate)?**

**UPDATE:**

I have another relationship in Position class:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "POSITION_NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Set<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
```

It is empty for the failing rows, but changing it to @Transient makes the issue go away.

Comment: How are you handling Hibernate session opening & closing?

Comment: Using tx:annotation-driven and org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager

Comment: have a loot at OpenSessionInView filter

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use OpenSessionInViewFilter that handles session opening and closing. You did not specify Spring / Hibernate versions so there may be need for adaptations.

web.xml filter definition:

```
<filter>    
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definetely not enough data in my question to find the right answer. Sorry for that.

So sharing my experience with the community: the problem was that the second key (POSITION_NUMBER) was not unique in the first collection so hibernate loaded this collection twice and the second initialization failed. Do not know what makes it ok in the debugger, but fixing the data fixed the issue.

So what I was really missing is the unique constraint on the key column.